# kapt - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: android, kotlin, kapt

This is the gradle log

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

e: /Users/mladenrakonjac/MyFirstKotlinApp/app/src/main/java/me/mnemonic/myloan/data/AppDatabase.kt: (1, 1): Some error(s) occurred while processing annotations. Please see the error messages above.
```

How do I fix the error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

Comment: I am also facing the exact same problem. I have tried everything provided in the referral links but nothing has worked out for me. Issue is, I am using databinding and problem seems to be while generating files by Kotlin compiler. Have you solved this problem @Mladen

Comment: @sandip I cannot recall, it was time ago. :/

Answer (score 0):

This goes in your gradle.properties file as the value for the org.gradle.jvargs parameter, e.g.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms2560m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m -XX:+UseCompressedOops
```